# Resizing Windows 7 bootcamp partition

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, partitioning, diskpart

I've installed Windows 7 on my Mac using bootcamp but stupidly only allocated it 25gb which isn't enough once I've installed Visual Studio and other stuff.

I was able to shrink the Mac partition using whatever tool it is in Mac OS Snow Leopard but it wouldn't let me increase the windows partition so I rebooted into Windows to try it but am still having problems:

I coudn't extend it using the disk management tool because the option is greyed out so I tried diskpart.exe but when I use the extend command with my partition selected it says:

```
Virtual Disk Service error: 
There is not enough usable space for this operation.
```

I've got 19.69gb of unallocated space though so am not sure why I'm having the problem. I don't want to have to wipe my Windows partition, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

[CampTune](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/camptune/) or [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php). I would suggest expanding your OS X partition again and using one of these tools.