# Turn off laptop back light without keyboard in Windows 7

Tags: display, keyboard, shortcuts, fn-key

How do I turn off my laptop's back light using a shortcut, or a program in Windows 7?

I have a Gateway NV59 and can press Fn + F8 to blacken the screen. At night, while watching a movie on my other monitor, it is a pain to try and find the right keys as they are far apart and hard to see with my lights off. Since I like to always be efficient, I would like to use my mouse instead of go from mouse, to keyboard, to mouse again (to hit play).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Volumouse**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html), from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/), can also change the brightness of the screen, along with of course changing the volume.

It's explained on this post: [**How To Dim or Increase The Brightness of Laptop or Notebook LCD Screen**](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/08/13/how-to-dim-or-increase-the-brightness-of-laptop-or-notebook-lcd-screen/)

[image]

You can also change the brightness using a slider with [**Desktop Lighter**](http://www.dimxsoft.com/dlighter/), but I don't know if it works with Windows 7:

[image]

I cannot test it as I don't have a laptop running Windows 7 but you could try **[Display Brightness Console](http://driveactivated.com/files/folders/programs/entry1049.aspx)**. More info at the bottom of this page about the [**Display Brightness Gadget**](http://driveactivated.com/projects/pages/display-brightness-vista-gadget.aspx):

> To use the console app, the following
> parameters are allowed:
>
> - *DisplayBrightnessConsole.exe*
>
>   This will return the current brightness level.
> - *DisplayBrightnessConsole.exe -getlevels*
>
>   This will return all possible brightness levels accepted by the display, separated by a new line.
> - *DisplayBrightnessConsole.exe 20* (or some other brightness level number)
>
>   This will set the brightness level of the display to the parameter given, in this case, 20.

Comment: Almost, but I want to be able to do it with one click. Is there a way I could make a shortcut to this program, and then use switches like -dim to do it?

Comment: Edited my post with yet one more tool :-) . If it works, you can create shortcuts to it with various brightness levels.

Comment: Those all adjust the brightness, they don’t actually turn the backlight off. ☹

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using only OS X until someone helps me with [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/183330/restoring-windows-7-from-a-system-image-on-a-boot-camp-partition-without-formatti), but as I recall it should be under Control Panel > Display > Adjust Brightness (on the left column).

[image]