# Restore VHD image in a specific partition

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, vhd, windows-7-restore

I'm having a similar issue described in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/183330/how-do-i-restore-windows-7-from-a-system-image-to-a-boot-camp-partition-without).
I have a Windows 7 VHD image and want to restore it, but I cannot let Windows Restore format the whole HD and destroy other partitions. I don't want to reinstall everything.
Is there a software that would simply restore the VHD file to a partition specified by me?